# scrapy : another method to avoid a lot of try except

Tags: python, scrapy

I want to ask a question
When I use css selector,`extract()`  will make the output thing a list
So if the css selector didn't have value
It will show error in terminal(like below),and the spider won't get any item in my json file

```
item['intro'] = intro[0]
exceptions.IndexError: list index out of range
```

So I use try and except to check the list is exists

```
    sel = Selector(response)
    sites = sel.css("div.con ul > li")
    for site in sites:
        item = Shopping_appleItem()
        links = site.css("  a::attr(href)").extract()
        title = site.css("  a::text").extract()
        date = site.css(" time::text").extract()

        try:
            item['link']  = urlparse.urljoin(response.url,links[0])
        except:
            print "link not found" 
        try:
            item['title'] = title[0]       
        except:
            print "title not found" 
        try:
            item['date'] = date[0]       
        except:
            print "date not found"
```

I feel I use a lot of try and except,and I don't know if it is a good way.
Please guide me a bit  Thank you

Comment: in except: use item['link'] = "no link" instead of printing message only. but you can print message as well

Answer (score 1):

You can use a separate function for extraction of data. 
e.g for text nodes, sample code is here

```
    def extract_text(node):
        if not node:
            return ''
        _text = './/text()'
        extracted_list = [x.strip() for x in node.xpath(_text).extract() if len(x.strip()) > 0]
        if not extracted_list:
            return ''
        return ' '.join(extracted_list)
```

and you can call this method like this

```
    self.extract_text(sel.css("your_path"))
```