# Order of iterations in start urls scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I have a list of urls in a csv file, I load this file in a pandas data frame, and use the column links as start urls

```
start_urls =  df['Links']
```

each link have this format

```
http://www.bbb.org/search/?type=name&input=%28408%29+998-0983&location=&tobid=&filter=business&radius=&country=USA%2CCAN&language=en&codeType=YPPA
```

this link is related with a phone number (408) 998-0983 which apears in the link as %28408%29+998-0983

for each of the pages in `df['Links']` I scrap some data, and save it in an item, so far so good, the problem I have is that the order in wich scrapy takes the list is not the same  that is is the data frame, so I can't merge the data I get with scrapy and the file that I already have becauses the rows doesn't match, also I would like to handle the exception when the page doesn't have the data an return a string, in wich part of the code could I do that, this is what I'm doing right now:

```
def parse(self, response):




    producto = Product()
    producto = Product(BBB_link = response.xpath('//*[@id="container"]/div/div[1]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/h4[1]/a').extract()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part of your question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21582989/python-scrapy-passing-properties-into-parser), which suggests over-riding `start_requests()` to add meta data. In your case I imagine you could add the phone number as meta data but any convenient link to your data frame would do. The order of the scraped data wont change but you will have enough information to relate to the original data in a database or spreadsheet.

```
class MySpider(CrawlSpider):

    def start_requests(self):
        ...
        yield Request(url1, meta={'phone_no': '(408) 998-0983'}, callback=self.parse)
        ...

def parse(self, response):
    item['phone_no'] = response.meta['phone_no']
```

For the case where no data is found you could test the list returned by your xpath. If it's empty then nothing was found.

```
producto = Product(BBB_link = response.xpath('//*[@id="container"]/div/div[1]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/h4[1]/a').extract()
if producto:
    <parse the page as normal>
    item['status'] = 'found ok'
else:
    item['status'] = 'not found'

yield item
```

Comment: what does yield stand for?

Comment: @LuisRamonRamirezRodriguez `yield` is a bit like a return statement, it hands the item dictionary to scrapy to put into the output pipeline. In python-speak the parse() routine is a generator and yield passes data to the calling outine. Pardon my Python, I'm a C programmer mostly.

Answer (score 1):

Scrapy works in an [asynchronous](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html) kind, that is why your idea doesn't work. A working solution would be to save the 'request.url' or 'response.url' together with the scraped result in a freshly generated output.csv

For the 2nd part of your question, have you tried [try & except](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25521303/scrapy-another-method-to-avoid-a-lot-of-try-except):

```
producto = Product()
try:
    producto = Product(BBB_link = response.xpath('//*[@id="container"]/div/div[1]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/h4[1]/a').extract()
except:
    producto = 'n/a'
```

Comment: I try it but doesn't work, scrapy handle the exception by default and returns an empty string, I believe I have to overwrite some method but I have no idea which one